# RegisterUser via WebApi from WPF Application

Tags: c#, wpf, asp.net-web-api

I wish my WPF application to communicate with a webapi I'm in the process (once I get past this) of writing. I've never connected to two up before and I'm struggling to perform the most basic of functions, to register a user.

I'm using the standard MVC + WebApi implementation from VS 2013 with individual accounts.

I'm looking at other SO code spinets to understand how to connect the two, but I keep getting bad request back when I call API.

I've tried two different methods to format the JSON, without success. 
Where am I going wrong?

```
  public async void RegisterUser()
    {

        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:2045/");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        var rbm = new RegisterBindingModel();
        rbm.UserName = "someemail";
        rbm.Password = "somepassword";
        rbm.ConfirmPassword = "somepassword";

        //MediaTypeFormatter jsonFormatter = new JsonMediaTypeFormatter();
        //HttpContent content = new ObjectContent<RegisterBindingModel>(rbm, jsonFormatter);
        //var resp = client.PostAsync("api/Account/Register", content).Result;

        var response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("api/Account/Register", rbm);

    }

}

public class RegisterBindingModel
{
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ok, the problem with trying to use other peoples code from SO to learn is that it sometimes has mistakes of its own.

Changed the model to

```
    public string Email { get; set; }
```

now works great :)